# Nexus3 docker registries behind HA proxy

Tags: docker, repository, nexus, haproxy, behind

I have a haproxy which serves as reverse proxy for services like jenkins and nexus. I have a requirement where the nexus docker repos can be accessed using that same haproxy. Currently I use : of nexus docker repos to login, pull and push the images. I tries the same config I had for jenkins and nexus but it did not work.

Comment: please can you share your config and the output of `haproxy -vv`